# Connecting an infile to an outfile in Python

Tags: python, sockets, stream, pipe, iostream

So I have two objects, each of which has an in and out stream. I want to connect them (in Python 3). Is there someway to map such that:

```
a.in = b.out
b.in = a.out
```

Or, do I have two write a poller for each direction? eg. this:

```
def thread_a():
  while(c = a.in.getc()):
    b.out.put(c)
def thread_b():
  while(c = b.in.getc()):
    a.out.put(c)
```

Comment: file? stream? What type of objects are these?

Comment: This isn't valid python which makes it harder to answer!

Comment: @tdelaney It is just psuedo code. But basically two tcp streams. Specifically from the sockets library. I want to connect one socket's recv/send functions to another socket's recv/send. I assume I can only do something like this with direct access to the underlying files/streams/pipes (idk correct lingo here.)

`def client(ip, port, message):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
        sock.connect((ip, port))
        sock.sendall(bytes(message, 'ascii'))
        response = str(sock.recv(1024), 'ascii')
        print("Received: {}".format(response))`